# How to create Google Form that can select which sheet to work on inside a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I need to create an attendance list that will make it easier for teachers to keep track of their students.

For that I'd need to select a name from a list of students before adding the date and time they show up for classes.

I want each student to have their own individual sheet inside of a single Spreadsheet (there aren't many), so I can generate reports afterwards, and at the same time keep it simple for not so tech-savvy teachers (a single Form would make things much easier).

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you facing? Remember that StackOverflow is not a free-code fabric.

Comment: Hi, @MassimilianoKraus, I'm sketching, actually. I just wanted to know if it's possible and start working on it. I'm sorry if I gave you the wrong impression, I never wanted anyone to code for me! Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer to your question but I've been trying to learn more about forms because we get a lot of questions about them.  It is possible to view the last response on a form Submit Event and distribute the responses to different sheets based upon the response data.  I did that below using a simple form that lets me select sheet names and an email.

Here's the code:

```
function formResponseEvent(e)
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bNqs3YeALOsIzMqnTg6SfK-7mHNcPZQ0ZuC81ee3LRU');
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var r = form.getResponses();
    irs = r[r.length-1].getItemResponses();
    ss.getSheetByName(irs[0].getResponse())
        .appendRow([irs[0].getResponse(), irs[1].getResponse()])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Cooper. This is more than helpful. I'll try to write some extended code using yours. I'm joining the group today!

Answer (score 0):

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var newResponse = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();

  ss.insertSheet(newResponse);
```

Comment: I believe the questioner wants the response separated into different student sheets.